# Variable within population of agents does not increment

Tags: anylogic

I have the following closed loop process model consisting of trucks moving between three stations (the three service blocks):

[image]

The three resource pools have a capacity on 1 and...:

- "shovel" is assigned to the "cLoad" service block
- "loadingPersonnel" is assigned to the "bLoad_unload" service block
- "dcPeronnel" is assigned to "dcUnload"

There will be generated 12 trucks and they operate in the closed loop until the simulation clock finishes. The truck agent class has a "loadingCap" parameter of value 17 (data type is double) and a "ballast" variable with an initial value of 0 (data type is double and access is public):

[image]

In the "on enter" action field of the "cornfieldBakery" moveTo-block from the first image, the following java code is inserted for incrementing the ballast variable with the loadingCap parameter:

```
agent.ballast += agent.loadingCap;
traceln("the current ballast of the leaving truck is: " + agent.ballast);
```

When I run the simulation I get the following in the console after the first truck enters the moveTo block:

"the current ballast of the leaving truck is: 17.0"

However, when I inspect the 1st agent instance during the simulation run, the variable ballast still remains at 0:

[image]

Are there any explanation to why the traceln() value and the "ballast" variable of the 1st instance differ from each other?

Comment: Why do you assume the first truck (presumably in a custom population written to by the Source block) is the one that flowed through the MoveTo block first? Depending on the delay times and seize criteria for your Service block, the first generated truck might not be the first to arrive into the MoveTo block.

Comment: In your traceln, print the index of the truck (via calling `getIndex` on it) so you can check.

Comment: Of course you might also be changing the `ballast` variables of the trucks somewhere else in the model too but I assume you've checked that!

Comment: Thanks for the critical thinking, Stuart. The getIndex() method was helpful to further debug. I will come back after a little more inspection of the problem.

Comment: Also probably relevant: in your screenshot, you are looking at the *second* truck in the population (index 1) not the first (index 0). In AnyLogic (and Java) 'lists' of things use zero-based indexing. It would have shown you the index 0 one initially when you double-clicked on the population (or navigated to it from the developer panel).

Comment: Yes, I looked into that. But the first truck (index 0) still remained at 0 and did not increment.